# Nested loops with Python cPickle

Tags: python, while-loop, pickle

I would like to be able to have a series of nested loops that use the same pickle file. See below:

```
def pickleRead(self):
    try:
        with open(r'myfile', 'rb') as file:
            print 'Reading File...'
            while True:
                try:
                    main = pickle.load(file)
                    id = main[0]
                    text =  main[1]
                    while True:
                        try:
                            data = pickle.load(file)
                            data_id = data[0]
                            data_text = data[1]
                            coefficient = Similarity().jaccard(text.split(),data_text.split())
                            if coefficient > 0 and data_text is not None:
                                print str(id) + '\t' + str(data_id) + '\t' + str(coefficient)
                        except EOFError:
                            break
                        except Exception as err:
                            print err
                except EOFError:
                    break

            print 'Done Reading File...'
        file.close()
    except Exception as err:
        print err
```

The second (inner) loop runs without any problems but the first one just does a single iteration and then stops. I am trying to grab a single row at a time then compare it against every other row in the file. There are several thousand rows and I have found that the cPickle module out performs anything similar. The problem is that it is limited in what is exposed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand. Is the file being modified as you go?

Comment: the file is not being edited its just read only.

Comment: Small tip: Part of the point of using `with` for file handling is that the file is closed automatically at the end; there is no need to explicitly close it yourself.  Also, since `file` is a Python built-in, you're recommended to use a different name (it's common to use `f` for this purpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I should say ben w's answer does explain the behavior you're experiencing.

As for your broader question of "how do I accomplish my task using Python?" I recommend just using a single loop through the file to load all the pickled objects into a data structure in memory (a dictionary with IDs as keys and text as values seems like a natural choice).  Once all the objects are loaded, you don't mess with the file at all; just use the in-memory data structure.  You can use your existing nested-loop logic, if you like.  It might look something like (pseudocode)

```
for k1 in mydict:
    for k2 in mydict:
        if k1 != k2:
            do_comparison(mydict[k1], mydict[k2])
```

Comment: I ended up scrapping the use of pickle and went with a straight database approach. This worked just fine for that.

Answer (score 4):

The inner loop only stops when it hits an `EOFError` while reading the file, so by the time you get to what would have been the second iteration of the outer loop, you've read the entire file. So trying to read more just gives you another `EOFError`, and you're out.